# How can this SQL query be improved?

Tags: sql, optimization, mariadb

This code actually works, but I guess it can be done in an easier way, or even more efficient (because I guess comparing strings like that is not a problem but may be). I tried to convert everything into datetime and not string but failed. 
This code takes the **date** and **time** row from one table, CONCATing them and compares it to the **datetime** row from another table. The result is: 2019-12-02 09:00:00
 It is just a regular Date, Time and Datetime parameters in the table. Like this Date **2019-11-17**, Time **09:00:00**, Datetime **2019-01-15 16:00:00**

```
SELECT
    MAX(CONCAT(f_ini, CONCAT( " ", h_ini)))
FROM posible_work
WHERE
    fk_id_asigned = 100573 AND
    (SELECT MAX(CONCAT(f_ini, CONCAT( " ", h_ini)))
     FROM posible_work) >
    (SELECT MAX(RIGHT(f_fin,19)) AS FechaAVI FROM next_work WHERE fk_id_worker = 100573)
```

Comment: FYI the `CONCAT` function in MariaDB/MySQL can take more than two parameters.  You were probably thinking of Oracle when you wrote that part of your query.

Comment: Adding some sample data from both tables would help your question.

Comment: Also, what are the data types of the various columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is just a regular Date, Time and Datetime parameters in the table. Like this  Date 2019-11-17, Time 09:00:00, Datetime 2019-01-15 16:00:00

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the thing is that it returns an string, when I would like to return a datetime. Anyways, can I ignore doing the select twice ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE possible_work`

Comment: "This code takes the date and time row from one table, CONCATing them and compares it to the datetime row from another table."  -- Your first step should be to change the schema to consistently use `DATETIME`, not splitting it.

Comment: I know, but it is not my database @RickJames :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you force `concat()` to be called twice when you can use it with 3 arguments (or more), one additional problem would be this condition:

```
(SELECT MAX(CONCAT(f_ini, CONCAT( " ", h_ini)))
 FROM posible_work) >
(SELECT MAX(RIGHT(f_fin,19)) AS FechaAVI FROM next_work WHERE fk_id_worker = 100573)
```

Why not use in the left side of the inequality just `concat(...)` and you repeat `SELECT...MAX(..)...`?
I don't think that this breaks your code's logic:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CONCAT(f_ini, ' ', h_ini))
FROM posible_work
WHERE
    fk_id_asigned = 100573 
    AND
    CONCAT(f_ini, ' ', h_ini) >
      (SELECT MAX(RIGHT(f_fin,19)) AS FechaAVI FROM next_work WHERE fk_id_worker = 100573)
```

Also it could be better if you did not hardcode `100573` twice.
Just use aliases properly:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CONCAT(p.f_ini, ' ', p.h_ini))
FROM posible_work p
WHERE
    p.fk_id_asigned = 100573 
    AND
    CONCAT(p.f_ini, ' ', p.h_ini) >
      (SELECT MAX(RIGHT(f_fin,19)) AS FechaAVI FROM next_work WHERE fk_id_worker = p.fk_id_asigned)
```